# "Too few parameters" error, even when I enter compatible datatypes

Tags: java, ms-access, ms-access-2007, jdbc-odbc

I'm doing a test application using JDK 7, Access 2007 and Microsoft Database Engine 2010.
When thru Java I defined a table with a 'REAL' datatype field and while entering Float or Double, it says

> [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1.

but if I enter numbers directly it accepts. What field types should I use?

Comment: Please post the stacktrace and any relevant code snippets. That will help us understand and diagnose the problem.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

A column defined as `REAL` using DDL will be created as "Number (Single)" in Access, which corresponds to `Float` in JDBC. So, you need to use `.setFloat()` to set your parameter value for that column, as in

```java
String sql = "INSERT INTO TableName (RealField) VALUES (?)";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setFloat(1, 3.14F);
```

This is the complete test code that works for me:

```java
import java.sql.*;

public class JDBCQuery {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String connectionString = "jdbc:odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};"
                + "DBQ=C:/Users/Public/mdbTest.mdb;";
        String tableName = "zzzJavaTest";
        String sql;
        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString)) {

            sql = String.format(
                    "DROP TABLE [%s]", 
                    tableName);
            try (Statement s = con.createStatement()) {
                try {
                    s.executeUpdate(sql);
                    System.out.println("Old table dropped.");
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    if (e.getMessage().endsWith("does not exist.")) {
                        System.out.println("Table did not previously exist.");
                    } else {
                        throw e;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace(System.out);
                System.exit(0);
            }

            sql = String.format(
                    "CREATE TABLE [%s] (id COUNTER PRIMARY KEY, numfield REAL)", 
                    tableName);
            try (Statement s = con.createStatement()) {
                s.executeUpdate(sql);
                System.out.println("New table created.");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace(System.out);
                System.exit(0);
            }

            sql = String.format(
                    "INSERT INTO [%s] (numfield) VALUES (?)", 
                    tableName);
            try (PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {
                ps.setFloat(1, 3.14F);
                ps.executeUpdate();
                System.out.println("New row added.");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(System.out);
                System.exit(0);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

}
```